# How to install sink drain pipe correctly

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, drain, sink

I'm trying to connect this drain assembly on my bathroom sink.
[image: drain assembly]

But when I connect to the sink it drips.
I tighten the top nut(arrow) with a channel lock, but it still drips.
Steps I took:

1. I put plumber's putty on the top
2. squeeze the top into drain hole.
3. attach the drain pipe to the top
4. turn the top nut tigh.
5. attach p-trap to drain pipe.

Am i doing something wrong, sometimes I hear a snapping sound and it seems that the drain pipe has loosen. Should I use Teflon tape?

Comment: Where is it dripping from?  Are you sure you're tightening the source of the leak?  But that "snapping" sound suggests to me that the nut is actually cracked and when you tighten it it's slipping over threads.

Answer (score 2):

I've had similar problems sometimes with sink drains. I'm guessing it's leaking were the rubber washer and the sink bottom connect? If so:

1. Make sure the black washer is fitting correctly. It should almost fit into the opening, but still have part of the curved section showing. Tightening the plastic nut will force more of the round section further and tighter into the sink bottom.
2. Check the sink drain opening for any irregularities. Run a finger tip around the drain edge and feel for bumps; it should be perfectly smooth.

I'm guessing the clicking sound you heard may be a stripped thread on the drain or a cracked nut. The PVC plastic is very easily cross threaded if not lined up correctly. Sometimes you can "uncross" the threads with a sharp utility knife.

If the two suggestions I first mentioned don't apply and nothing is working it might be worth noting that the type of drain in your photo (the accordion or flexible-type) is not up to code anymore. It may be easier to purchase a new rigid P Trap.